# glib, (FIFO pipe) fd leak using GMainLoop and GSource timeout

Tags: glib, file-descriptor

I've been having some issues with some file descriptors hanging when using Glibs GMainLoop.
I've narrowed it down to a simple loop having one event.

I'm monitoring the file descriptors when running the program and notice that there are a couple of file descriptors that never gets closed.

Please see this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static gboolean
timeout(gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("## %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    g_main_loop_quit((GMainLoop*)user_data);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    g_type_init();

    printf("Check lsof now...\n");
    sleep(10);
    printf("--- time's up ---\n");

    GMainContext *ctx = g_main_context_new();
    GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new(ctx, FALSE);
    g_main_context_push_thread_default(ctx);

    GSource *timer = g_timeout_source_new(2000);
    g_source_set_callback(timer, timeout, loop, NULL);
    g_source_attach(timer, ctx);

    g_main_loop_run(loop);

    g_main_context_pop_thread_default(ctx);
    g_source_unref(timer);
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);
    g_main_context_unref(ctx);

    printf("Check lsof now...\n");
    sleep(10);
    printf("--- time's up ---\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Where it is marked in the code, I am checking the number of file descriptors the program has open. At the first checkpoint there are 3 (ignoring libs etc):

```
a.out   16333 hansm    0u   CHR 136,43      0t0      46 /dev/pts/43
a.out   16333 hansm    1u   CHR 136,43      0t0      46 /dev/pts/43
a.out   16333 hansm    2u   CHR 136,43      0t0      46 /dev/pts/43
```

At the second checkpoint there are five:

```
a.out   16873 hansm    0u   CHR 136,43      0t0        46 /dev/pts/43
a.out   16873 hansm    1u   CHR 136,43      0t0        46 /dev/pts/43
a.out   16873 hansm    2u   CHR 136,43      0t0        46 /dev/pts/43
a.out   16873 hansm    5r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 149228995 pipe
a.out   16873 hansm    6w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 149228995 pipe
```

Why are these pipes not closed?

Valgrind reports no error (except some 'possibly lost memory').

The fd's (5 and 6 in example above) are opened when doing

```
GMainContext *ctx = g_main_context_new();
```

And obviously never closed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's a really good question, and I don't know the answer. I did notice that you forgot the `return FALSE;` statement in the `timeout` function. You should add it because otherwise it's undefined whether or not the source gets destroyed after it fires. However, adding it does not solve the problem. The only other comment I have, which I assume you already know, is that if you omit `g_main_context_push_thread_default` and `g_main_context_pop_thread_default` then the problem goes away. So I guess that's a clue.

Comment: I don't see any pipe on my system. What I see is an `anon_inode`.  this is glib 2.32.3-1 on debian sid amd64.  It might changed in the mean time?